# Updating the collection by timeout with constant availability

Tags: java, scala, flink-streaming

Is there a Java/Scala collection (List, Array or something similar) that automatically updates whole collection content after a given timeout? But with one feature that updating will happen in another thread and the old data will be available during updating.

My case is the enrichment of the Flink stream with a periodically updated collection, the data of which I get from PostgreSQL. I do not need to query the database for each message. I do a full data download (SELECT * FROM table) from the table every N minutes. And I don't want to make a pause for updating data.

Comment: You probably need to use a caching system that will give you eviction policy based on a time to live, read/write through, etc.

Comment: Yep caching (with JCache) is probably the best way to answer your specific need, until the time to live end you get the data from the cache and as soon as it's finished it will query the database and put in the cache. And it's thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viktor,

I guess caching is one of the best solution you can use. But if you are not aware on caching, following answer will help you.

**Solution**

You can use TimerTask class to run a specific method timely manner. Following simple example will give you an idea.

- ListUpdater (which is a TimerTask child)

  import java.util.TimerTask;

  public class ListUpdater extends TimerTask{

  ```
    @Override
    public void run() {

      // You can write your code to update your list.
      System.out.println("Updating list");

    }
  ```

  }
- Application Class

  public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

  ```
      TimerTask task = new ListUpdater();

      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(task, 1000,6000);
   }
  ```

  }

**In this example, the timer will print the “Updating list” message every 6 seconds, with a 1 second delay for the first time of execution.**

There are lot of thread safe collections in java. You are free to use any of them.

- ConcurrentLinkedQueue
- ArrayBlockingQueue
- LinkedBlockingDeque
- LinkedBlockingQueue
- PriorityBlockingQueue
- SynchronousQueue
- DelayQueue

Or to create a brand new thread-safe list:

List newList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());